# Efficient way to set the header and footer in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile page has a very long list to scroll ,also they have fixed header and footer
when i scroll down the list the header and footer disappears while scrolling and they appear when scrolling stops. Is there anyway to make header and footer hardcore fixing in top and bottom of the screen? Thanks.

Note: I have used `data-position=fixed`

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
[fixed positioning in mobile browsers](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, data-position=fixed translates to position:fixed, and this refresh "bug" is a limitation of some mobile browsers, I'm afraid.